# How to add one class at a time if two divs are ovelapped in the same position

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

I am stuck in one problem and tried a lot but couldn't get the solution.

What happens is, there is an mp3 player and below that player there is a strip what holds pictures (comments from users) based on the mp3 progress.

When ever the progress bar of the player reach the start of the image it ads "active" class to the image so people can see that at this time this user commented.

Now the problem I am facing is that at 01:46 there are two images that overlap each other and due to this overlap the javascript is adding active class to both images which I don't want, I want if the progress bar reach the start of the first image it will make it active but as soon as the second image starts (which is overlapped) the second image gets active so that there would be only 1 active at a time. same as soundcloud comments.

No matter if the first image duration will be less but this is what i wanted to achieve, as these images will be dynamic and user can choose where ever they want to comment i can not give the specific class to overlapped images so something needs to be done through javascript which i am stuck badly.

Because now there are two overlapped but in future it can be three four or how many overlapped so i want a effect that when we move the mouse from left to right on these images how the hover effect makes pictures active and as the second picture gets in focus that become active, i want it to be that way.

Can any expert help me with this?

I am using this function to get the left position of the progress bar meets the image to add "active" class and when the width of the image end it will remove the active class

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 function highlightImg(progress){
 progress = parseFloat(parseFloat(''+progress).toFixed(1));
    var imgs = $('img.comment');
    imgs.map(function (i, im)
    {   
      var img = $(im);
      var currentImgLeftPos = parseFloat(parseFloat(im.style.left).toFixed(1));
      var currentImgRightPos = $(this).width() / $(this).parent().width() * 100;
      console.log(progress);
      console.log('left' ,currentImgLeftPos);
      img.removeClass('active'); // remove active from other images
            if (progress > currentImgLeftPos - 1 && progress < currentImgLeftPos + currentImgRightPos  ) {
                $('#imgwidimg').text('this'+currentImgRightPos);
        img.addClass('active'); // add the class when needed
      }
    }
  );
}
```

And with this function i am making the jplayer progress update

```
$('#jquery_jplayer_2').on($.jPlayer.event.timeupdate, function(e){
   var progress = document.querySelector('.jp-play-bar').style.width;
   highlightImg(progress);
});
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XLNCY/22643/) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: What have you tried? Please post more code you’ve used.

Comment: Hi, yes i tried alot i have made this fiddle please check http://jsfiddle.net/XLNCY/22643/

Comment: I mean put the code in your question.

Comment: Alright ill put the code in this question, actually i am currently logged from a phone will get back as i will be on from pc, ill comment here.. thanks jacob

Comment: Yes, also, your tags seem a little... off.

Comment: Ill update the tags

Comment: Edited your tags, but I'll let you insert your own code. I recommend making it *MUCH* smaller. Your JS code section is 3668 lines. There is no way that's a *minimally* complete, verified, example.

Comment: Yea because i have put all the code just to make the jplayer work, that doesnt need to do any stuff just the code on the top are is where i am stuck at..  and just the problem is when there are two images overlapi g each other both are taking active class but i want one at a time.

Comment: @Draco18s i have updated the question - added the codes.

Comment: @JacobB. i have updated the question - added the codes.

Comment: Now all you need to do is edit your tags

Comment: I think tags are relevant, what do you mean by edit, please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with this.

```
 if (progress > currentImgLeftPos - 1 && progress < currentImgLeftPos + currentImgRightPos  ) {
                $('#imgwidimg').text('this'+currentImgRightPos);
        imgs.removeClass("active");  //add this line to your code
        img.addClass('active'); // add the class when needed
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help can you update the fiddle please?

Comment: Sumair bhai! You are greatt!! Thankyou soo much !! It worked amazingly